# filectime() is not changing (even if file is deleted manually)

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php

function logAction($action,$file){

    /**
     * delete the file
     */

    if((time()-filectime(ROOT_PATH.'/logs/'.$file)) > LOG_CLEAN){

        unlink(ROOT_PATH.'/logs/'.$file);

    };

    /**
     * write the action
     */

    $f = fopen(ROOT_PATH.'/logs/'.$file,'a');

    $data = "[".date('d-m-Y H:i:s')."] ".$action."\n";

    fwrite($f,$data);

    fclose($f);

    return true;

};

?>
```

The problem is: filectime() is not changing values. When I write it down, it stays the same, even if a new file is generated (for example if I delete the log file manually).

What's the problem with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result `filectime()` function are cached. Use `clearstatcache()` to clear the cache. The `clearstatcache()` function clears the file status cache. check the documentation here [php filectime()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_filectime.asp) [php clearstatcache()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_clearstatcache.asp)